# I keep getting an error on my sql code

Tags: oracle

I am working on a sql project and I keep getting this error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
> *Cause:
> *Action: Error at Line: 4 Column: 56

this is my code:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME,
SUBSTR(PRODUCT_NAME, INSTR(PRODUCT_NAME, '(') + 1),

INSTR(PRODUCT_NAME, ')') - INSTR(PRODUCT_NAME, '(') - 1)

FROM PRODUCTS
```

Comment: Count your parentheses.

Comment: MySQL != Oracle.